# How do I debug when implementing the handleOpenURL message?

Tags: iphone, ios-simulator

I'm writing an iPhone app that can be started via a custom URL. So, I override - `(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url`

To test my changes, I have to run the app in the simulator, then quit out and launch Safari. I then type in my custom URL in the address bar to launch the app.

But every time I launch, the app crashes. I'm trying to figure out why, but when I set a breakpoint and launch the app from the home screen (instead of in XCode) it doesn't seem to attach.

I even tried putting NSLog statements in the handleOpenURL message, but they don't get printed to the console.

I suppose I could create UIAlertViews but... yeah, yikes. Any other way to connect to a debug session in the Simulator?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In Xcode 4, you can edit your target's scheme and in the "Run" section, "Info" tab, you can choose the "Wait for MyApp.app to launch" option:

[image]

This will cause the debugger to wait until the next time your app starts, and then attach to that process rather than creating a new process for you. This will let you launch your app manually from Safari and use the debugger.

Comment: This should be the new answer now that Apple has fixed this in Xcode 4. Much easier!

Comment: This does hook the debugger, but NSLog and stdout appear to be lost :(

Answer (score 7):

Open up Console.app (in the Utilities folder). Your log messages should appear there.

Comment: To expand upon this, `NSLog` statements won't show up in the standard XCode console if the app wasn't launched from XCode (i.e. on the phone or within the simulator).

Comment: This didn't work for me, but using the Console tab in the XCode Organizer window did...

Answer (score 1):

Can you write a Unit Test that would exercise the functionality of your AppDelegate?

Comment: I actually tried another way that is similar - I put a call to handleOpenURL in the applicationDidFinish launching message, and then launched as normal, and I was able to step through. And doing it that way didn't crash anything, it was only crashing via the steps described above.

Comment: Is your handleOpenURL handler is relying on something that is setup in applicationDidFinishLaunching?

Comment: Also, instead of trying to log to the console, can you save some information to a file?

Answer (score 1):

I have not tried this but how about adding a breakpoint instruction inline in your code:

```
#if TARGET_CPU_ARM == 1
#define breakpoint() __asm__ volatile ("bkpt 0")
#else   // !ARM - assume INTEL. Everything else will break
#define breakpoint() __asm__ volatile ("int3");
#endif
```

Answer (score 1):

add the following as first line in the hadleOpenURL:

[NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:30.0]
and put the breakpoint on the next line after.

After your application is invoked, you will have 30 seconds to go to XCode and select from menu: Run/"Attach to Process" and select your application name from the list.
You debugger should stop at the your breakpoint.

Don't forget to remove the sleepForTimeInterval when you are finished!